# Transferring the the data from a file to pandas dataframe, which have no file extension

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I like to use `SMS Spam Collection Data Set` which can be found on [UCI Machine Learning Repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/SMS+Spam+Collection#), to build a classification model. The data file that is shared on the repository has no file extension. The data is look like the following

```
    ham Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only in bugis n great world la e buffet... Cine there got amore wat...
    ham Ok lar... Joking wif u oni...
    spam    Free entry in 2 a wkly comp to win FA Cup final tkts 21st May 2005. Text FA to 87121 to receive entry question(std txt rate)T&C's apply 08452810075over18's
    ham U dun say so early hor... U c already then say...
    ham Nah I don't think he goes to usf, he lives around here though
    spam    FreeMsg Hey there darling it's been 3 week's now and no word back! I'd like some fun you up for it still? Tb ok! XxX std chgs to send, £1.50 to rcv
```

Where ham or spam should be the class attribute and the rest of the portion is the message. How could I transfer the dataset into Pandas dataframe? The dataframe should like the following

```
Message Class   Messages
ham         Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only in bugis n great world la e buffet... Cine there got amore wat...
ham        Ok lar... Joking wif u oni...
spam      Free entry in 2 a wkly comp to win FA Cup final tkts 21st May 2005. Text FA to 87121 to receive entry question(std txt rate)T&C's apply 08452810075over18's
ham       U dun say so early hor... U c already then say...
ham      Nah I don't think he goes to usf, he lives around here though
spam    FreeMsg Hey there darling it's been 3 week's now and no word back! I'd like some fun you up for it still? Tb ok! XxX std chgs to send, £1.50 to rcv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file seems like a `.txt` tab separated, so you can use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer= "SMSSpamCollection",
                 header=None, sep="\t", names=["Message Class", "Messages"])
```

##### # Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
df= pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", sep="\t")
df.dropna(how="any", inplace=True, axis=1)
df.columns = ['label', 'message']
df.head()
```